# Why state change only if I decrease the quantity but don't work if I want to delete the card

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
handleDelete = cardId => {
        const updatedCards = [...this.state.cards];
        if (updatedCards[cardId].quantity==0)  // this does not work
            updatedCards.filter(card => card.id != cardId);
        else // this works
            --updatedCards[cardId].quantity;
        this.setState({cards:updatedCards});
    }
```

It only works if I decrease the quantity, but if quantity is 0 and I press delete, the card is still there. It doesn't go away.

But if I only put this it deletes the card correctly:

```
handleDelete = cardId => {
    const updatedCards = this.state.cards.filter(card => card.id != cardId);
    this.setState({cards:updatedCards});
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't do anything:

```
updatedCards.filter(card => card.id != cardId);
```

It returns a new array, but that new array is ignored.  So nothing is *changing* in the state.  State is *technically* updated, because you have a new object and a new array, so the component re-renders.  But the new state has all the same data as the previous state.

Contrast that with your working example:

```
const updatedCards = this.state.cards.filter(card => card.id != cardId);
```

In this case you're capturing the result of the `filter` operation and setting that result to state.  So the data is now different when the component re-renders.

Comment: OK, got it. but why it doesn't work neither this way:
`updatedCards = updatedCards.filter(card => card.id != cardId);` and then `this.setState({cards:updatedCards});` ?
Shouldn't it work since I am saving the new object address in "updatedCards" ?

Comment: @Allexj: When you debug, what specifically "doesn't work" about it?  Can you provide a runnable [mcve] which demonstrates the problem?  Is the `filter` operation not doing what you expect, or is the `if` condition not doing what you expect?  Now is the time for very specific debugging to identify the values and results of every operation involved.

Comment: lol I literally didn't realize I created a CONST updatedCards lol.